# Conexiones en fott-preview de Azur Form Recognizer

Tags: azure, blob, microsoft

Deseo realizar la conexión entre el label tool de Microsoft para el Form Recognizer, y un Blob Storage de un Storage Account.

de acuerdo a este tutorial, https://github.com/microsoft/OCR-Form-Tools, en la sección de create connections, explica que solo basta con configurar el CORS y generar el SAS del contenedor BLOB.

Cuando se guarda la conexión no se genera ningún error, pero al iniciar un nuevo proyecto este genera un error que dice.

> no tiene cuenta de almacenamiento. Verifique su token SAS en la página
> de conexiones

Comment: Transcribe las configuraciones _como texto, con formato_. Son prácticamente ilegibles. Lee [ask].

Comment: gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft tiene publicadas muchas versiones de su herramienta para realizar el etiquetamiento para entrenar Form Recognizer

Mi error era que estaba entrando a una versión desactualizada, esta: https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net

Se tiene que ingresa a la URL de la última versión, en mi caso funcionó ingresando a https://fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net

Puedes ver más sobre la documentación oficial [aquí](https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net)